# Snap entire selection to the 3d cursor in edit mode

Tags: snapping

Is there any way to snap an entire selection to the 3d cursor in edit mode?

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor* snaps each individual vertex to the cursor, so the shape is lost:

[image: mesh before snapping]

[image: mesh after snapping]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you grab a recent build of Blender of r58453 or greater (2.7x up), you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor (Offset)*

The official commit can be found [here](http://www.miikahweb.com/en/blender/svn-logs/commit/58453). I could not find any documentation but it's pretty intuitive.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this in blender 2.68 is to open the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>), and copy-paste the values from the 3D-cursor location fields to the transform median fields by hovering the mouse over them and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
This does the same thing as the new snapping with offset that's implemented in the current trunk, as stated by iKlsR. My answer will be irrelevant once blender 2.69 sees daylight.

Answer (score 2):

A cheap workaround could be done using proportional editing with constant offset.

1. Enable proportional editing (select connected)
2. Set the type to constent
3. Grab one vertex and scale the proportional editing up.
4. Move

Comment: Interesting solution, Unfortunately does not work with snapping. also limited when the selection is part of a larger mesh.