# snap / selection the deformation bones of my bird to the cursor does not work as expected

Tags: modeling, rigging, snapping

I'm following the piero training course video tutorial and I reached the rigging stage (for who has already completed the tutorial,I'm on the  "23_piero_rigging_wing-part_1" on minute 31:00).

I'm trying to rig the wing of the bird. This is what happens to me when I do "snap / selection" the deformation bones of my bird to the cursor :

[what happens to my bird](https://sendvid.com/9bk9uopn)

instead,this is what should happen (you will see only a little part of the full video) :

[this is what should happens](https://sendvid.com/ewigovls)

Can someone tell me why ?

Comment: it seems this is because you are in edit mode and in the tutorial, he is in pose mode

Comment: check it better,at the beginning he does it in pose mode,but then he switches to edit mode.

Comment: In versions of Blender newer than one in the video this is *Selection To Cursor (Offset)*. Possible duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/snap-entire-selection-to-the-3d-cursor-in-edit-mode.

Comment: @MrZak there is a way to reproduce this problem. Switching to pose mode, selecting the bones differently, coming back to edit mode... but I am not already able to reproduce it constantly

Comment: OK, yes... this is it : if the bone are selected from the pose mode, you get the problem... if they are selected from edit mode all is ok. Can you confirm, @Marietto ?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem : check here : http://sendvid.com/wq17muqr

Comment: and this is what happens if I use "Selection To Cursor (Offset)" : http://sendvid.com/zpmkdey1

Comment: @MrZak, this is not an offset problem, it seems to be confirmed here https://developer.blender.org/T48839. So the solution below may be ok

Comment: excuse me,I didn't understand,what's the solution ?

Comment: @Marietto as I said last time, you should not be flagging your own posts for stuff like this. For both cases asking a question on our [meta](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/) would be a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an unexpected behavior.

- If you select the bones in pose mode, then switch to edit mode :

[image]

- If you select the bones in edit mode :

[image]