# Move selected faces/verts towards 3D cursor without scaling

Tags: modeling

If I am in an mesh edit mode, I can select several faces, then press S to scale and set the target to be a 3D cursor. When I move the mouse, the selected faces will start to scale and move towards the 3D cursor.

Is this possible to do this with translation instead of scaling? I want the selected faces to move towards the 3D cursor in a straight line just like in scaling, BUT without any scaling going on. (Another way to imagine it would be pressing G to move it, but it would move in a straight line towards the 3D cursor.)

Answer (score 1):

You can snap it to the cursor using <kbd>Shift + S</kbd> and select "*Selection to cursor (offset)*".

Comment: That just merges everything on the cursor. I don't want to scale or reshape the selection I want to only move it. Same as pressing G and moving things with a mouse, except here they will move towards the 3D cursor.

Comment: @Askerman if you snap selection with Selection To Cursor **(Offset)** option then nothing will be merged, selection will be moved as is to the cursor location, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/snap-entire-selection-to-the-3d-cursor-in-edit-mode